# Shared library present with different name

Tags: unix, shared-libraries

I compiled my program with `gcc` using openssl crypto library.
I moved the executable to an other system, and after installing openssl tried to run it. I got the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What I understand from the following the library is present, but has another name:

```
locate libcrypto
/usr/lib64/.libcrypto.so.1.0.2f.hmac
/usr/lib64/.libcrypto.so.10.hmac
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2f
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc
```

Can I somehow tell the binary to use one of the present libraries? Or is there a way to install the one which is required?

The compilation was done on Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit, tried to run on Fedora 4.2.3-300.fc23.x86_64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow tell the binary to use one of the present libraries?

No, you can't: there is a *reason* these libraries have a different name: they are not ABI-compatible. If you managed to somehow tell the binary to use the other library, the result will be a crash if you are lucky, or a silent corruption if you are not.

(BTW, you *can* try this by creating a symbolic link: `ln -s libcrypto.so.1.0.2f libcrypto.so.1.0.0`, but you've been warned *not* to do this).

> is there a way to install the one which is required?

Sure: you should be able to copy `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` from Ubuntu machine to Fedora one, assuming you can't find a Fedora package that provides it.